# "Could not find or load main class" when passing system properties in Java

Tags: java

When I run this in Windows 11 command prompt:

```
java -Damp.server=mfpp ^
    -Damp.setting2=value2 ^
    -Damp.setting3=value3 ^
    -jar target\MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

it runs fine.
But when my colleague runs it (using Powershell, if that's relevant), they get this error:

```
Could not find or load main class .server=mfpp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /server=mfpp
```

Why when I run it does it take the whole thing as a system setting, yet when they run it, it seems like it has a problem with the period and isn't reading it as "amp.server"?

Comment: It most certainly does seem that way. What system are you on, and what system is your colleague on? I ask because that "caret as line continuation" trick is Windows-specific. If your colleague is on a Linux or Mac machine, that should be a backslash for them.

Comment: Are you sure your colleague is not typing a space after the dot out of habit?

Comment: Yes, no spaces. It's a Powershell issue. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685184/powershell-run-java-process-problem) got me on the right track.
Turns out Powershell parses these `-D` arguments differently, so enclosing the arguments in quotation marks is what's needed (apparently single or double works).

```
#Powershell: backticks
java '-Damp.server=mfpp' `
     '-Damp.setting2=value2' `
     '-Damp.setting3=value3' `
    -jar target\MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Or use the Command Prompt (with carets for line continuation and no quotes needed).